# How do I get rid of this white stuff on my pumpkin leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, pumpkins, mold

The leaves on my pumpkin plants have what looks like a white mold growing on them.

What is this?

If it is harmful, how do I treat it?

Comment: Would be easier to answer if we could see it. Can you post a photo?

Comment: Good point. I will have to take some pictures and post when I get back from work this evening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is almost certainly **Powdery Mildew** (see photo), a fungal disease that prefers high  humidity and occurs most often during a spell of cool days and humid nights. A severe attack will destroy plants' leaves and reduce their yield. You can control it chemically with a copper or sulfur-based fungicide, or organically, using the following recipe, which I haven't tried myself but I gather is very effective. It is based on research done by Cornell University:

1 tablespoon each of baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) and either a light horticultural oil or regular vegetable oil, to 1 gallon of water. Shake well before and during application.

[Powdery Mildew on Pumpkin Leaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Uxz.jpg)

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the stuff.

Comment: could this happen on eggplant?  Our looks very similar.

Comment: Yes, it often does.

Comment: That recipe seems to br working very well!

Comment: Glad it's proving effective. Thanks for the feedback!